# swift how to programmatically reposition seque button

Tags: swift, xcode, segue

How can I programmatically relocate the position of my view's seque button "GO"?

My seque "GO" button appears on device at different position (ie. middle) than I set in storyboard (far right).

I want to position it to the right to uncover the UIView

Here is declaration within viewcontroller code:
@IBOutlet weak var startButton: UIButton!

..Main shows view in landscape and button is 5 times wider than it appears on device, though shown device size is what I want.

Here are inspector settings.............
[image]

And here button appears unexplainably in the middle.....
[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with UIKit?  If so, the simplest way is to set layout constraints for the button in `Main.storyboard`, then if necessary adjust them at runtime from `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.  This can be done easily by setting up `IBOutlets` to each constraint you want to access the value of programmatically.

Comment: Or, you could use the `UIButton` `init` method that takes a `frame` parameter (`CGRect`), and specify the position of the button that way.

Comment: How is your button set up currently?  Does it have any constraints, and are they set from the storyboard or programmatically?  Including the relevant code from your app would help with answering your question.  The image isn't particularly useful other than to show that the button is overlapping the text view.

Comment: Is the problem that the button starts out where you want it in portrait mode, then moves to cover up the view when you rotate to landscape mode?

Comment: Quack:  Thanks for help.  Not using UIKit.  Button set up in Main.storyboard.  No, not:  "button starts out where you want it in portrait mode, then moves to cover up the view when you rotate to landscape mode" ...Main shows view in landscape.

Comment: The only related code is shown above:   @IBOutlet weak var startButton: UIButton!

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the two images showing the storyboard, it appears that you have a `Misplaced View`.  That is what the orange lines with numbers next to them mean.  This is something that can happen if you set constraints for an interface element (like the button in your example) and then change your mind about where you want it, and drag the element to a different position on the view controller.

In your example, it appears that the button has its constraints set for the center of the view controller's main background view, but then the button was moved to the lower right.  This is very easy to fix:  if you want the button to stay in the lower right, you'll just have to update its constraints.

The easiest way to do this (in my experience, at least) would be to first bring up the "View Controller Scene" sidebar (not sure what it's officially called, but you can see it circled in yellow in the image below).  This lets you see which constraints belong to which views, so you can find your button's old constraints and delete them.  If you select the orange lines in the Interface Builder, it should highlight the corresponding constraints in the sidebar (also shown in the image).  Then, just delete the ones that pertain to your 'GO' button.  This will stop the button from reverting back to the center of the screen when you run your app.

The next step is to add constraints for where you *actually* want the button.  This can be done by just selecting the button in Interface Builder, opening the `Add New Constraints` menu (it's the symbol circled in green), and tapping the 4 red dotted lines (which should then turn into solid lines), then pressing the `Add Constraints` button at the bottom of the popup menu to finalize them.  This should fix the button in its desired location in the lower right of the screen.

[image: storyboard image showing constraints]